# Autocompletion when programming for openoffice

Tags: autocomplete, openoffice.org, openoffice-basic

This may be a stupid question but is there any way to get autocompletion when programming macros in StarBasic?

I know there's a plugin for eclipse if you want to program in java but I haven't been able to find any editor at all that supports BASIC and autocompletion?

If there's no solution, is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no IDE for openoffice basic that supports Intellisense But there is a work around that i use.
Write your code Visual Basic 6.0 IDE and then paste it to openoffice basic ide. Since most of the syntax is similar, this way can save your lot of time.